# Applying a list of Python functions to a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, kernel-density

I have a list of precomputed and stored Python lambda functions, e.g.:

```
fn_list = [lambda x: x + 2 for x in some_data]
```

Now, I would like that for a Tensor:

```
X = tf.placeholder(..., shape=[None, 1])
```

to apply each of the functions in `fn_list` to each of the values in the `None` dimension of `X`.

The output would ideally have the same shape as the `X` by using `tf.reduce_sum` to squash all the results from `fn_list` for each of the values in `X`.

Below is a sample of code that shows what I'd want from the problem above:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def _get_gaussian(loc=0.0, scale=1.0):
    return lambda x: (1/scale * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp(-0.5 * np.power((x-loc)/scale, 2))

data = np.random.normal(3, 1.25, 100)

fn_list = [_get_gaussian(loc=x, scale=0.2) for x in data]

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

pred = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.map_fn(lambda fn_: tf.reduce_sum(fn_(x)), fn_list), X)
```

The code above would basically perform some sort of Kernel Density Estimation by first computing a normal distribution around each of the points in `data`, storing the kernels in `fn_list`.
Then, for a certain Tensor `X`, it could compute the likelihood of each of the values in `X`.

`pred` would now be a Tensor of shape `X.shape`.

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you need to loop through `fn_list`, applying each function in turn to `X`, using the `map` function.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. However, using `tf.map_fn` leads to a `TypeError`.

Comment: ... which means that you *almost* know how to do this.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Sure, I will edit the post now. I didn't have any particular problematic code, since this is a smaller piece in a bigger puzzle. I will adhere to MCVE from now on.

Comment: Much better.  I'm not quite good enough with PANDAS to nail this for you, but I did upvote.  :-)

Comment: @Prune much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My brain hurts a bit trying to follow this :) but basically, if you break out the last line like this:

```
pred = tf.map_fn( lambda x: tf.map_fn(lambda fn_: tf.reduce_sum(fn_(x)),
                                      fn_list),
                  X)
```

then your issue is now clearer. Namely that the inner `tf.map_fn` is trying to map the function `tf.reduce_sum( fn_( x ) )` onto `fn_list`, but the latter is a list of *functions* not a tensor. Furthermore, the outer `tf.map_fn` is trying to map the *result of the inner map* onto X, but that result is *not a function* but a tensor. So some rethinking and restructuring of this code is in order, no mapping, Gaussian expressed as Tensorflow operations, maybe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

data = np.random.normal(3, 1.25, 5)

#X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])
X = tf.constant( [ 1, 2, 3 ], dtype = tf.float32 )

scale = 0.2
coeff = np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) / scale
X_fn = []
for idx in xrange( len ( data ) ):
    x = data[ idx ]
    X_fn.append(
        coeff * tf.exp( - 0.5 * tf.pow( ( X - x ) / scale, 2 ) )
    )

X1 = tf.stack( X_fn, axis =  0 )
X2 = tf.reduce_sum( X1, axis = 1 )
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( X2 ) )
```

Output:

> [3.7835757e-09 9.0623178e+00 9.2027439e-03 2.7527404e-01 1.1571876e+00]

The code above works but I'm not completely sure it does what you want exactly. I still hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the brain hurt I've caused. This answer solves my problem, thank you so very much for the help.